# Show loading status

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, loading

In my sample application using JSF2.0 + Richfaces3.3.3. 
I want to show loading status for all a4j action.

It means, when i click button, then show loading status in modal panel.
**Otherwise**, When i click button, show loading status and at the same time no more a4j action for before complete that process.
After complete that process, i do other action or click same button.

In my following sample code, i show loading status for button action. but i can multiple click same button during loading time.

So i need to prevent any action during loading time.

```
<f:view>
   <html>
      <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      </head>
      <body>
            <h:form id="sampleForm" binding="#{Sample.initForm}">                

            <a4j:commandButton value="Sample"
                               action="#{Sample.sampleButtonAction}"/>

            <a4j:status>
                <f:facet name="start">
                    <h:graphicImage value="ai.gif" alt="ai"/>
                </f:facet>
            </a4j:status>

        </h:form>
</body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

Sample.java

```
package myapp.beans;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm;

public class Sample
{
    private HtmlForm initForm;    

   public String sampleButtonAction()
   {
    System.out.println("Sample Button assigned....");

    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception occured....");
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public HtmlForm getInitForm(){

    return initForm;
}

public void setInitForm(HtmlForm initForm){
    this.initForm = initForm;
}
}
```

Help me,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
<a4j:status
    onstart="#{rich:component('procesoEsperaPopupPanel')}.show(); return false;"
    onstop="#{rich:component('procesoEsperaPopupPanel')}.hide(); return false;">
</a4j:status>

<rich:popupPanel id="procesoEsperaPopupPanel" autosized="true" moveable="true">
    <h:graphicImage name="ai.gif" alt="ai"/>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<h:form id="sampleForm" binding="#{Sample.initForm}">

  <a4j:commandButton value="Sample" action="#{Sample.sampleButtonAction}"/>

    <a4j:status
         onstart="javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('progressWaitModalPanel');"    
           onstop="javascript:Richfaces.hideModalPanel('progressWaitModalPanel');">                   

     </a4j:status>

    <rich:modalPanel  id="progressWaitModalPanel" autosized="true" moveable="true" >
           <h:graphicImage value="ai.gif" alt="ai"/>
    </rich:modalPanel>

 </h:form>
```